# Is this question really "Off topic: asking for advice?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

[MIS vs IT Degrees](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/136094/mis-vs-it-degrees/136096#136096)

It's closed now as "off topic, asking for advice on a specific choice."

My interpretation is that the asker is *not* asking which degree to pursue; instead they're asking *does it matter* which one is pursued? Personally, I don't see that as a typical "asking for advice on a specific choice" type question, and it strikes me as on topic, answerable, and valuable. We can give insight into how hiring managers typically evaluate the degree they see on a resume. Does anyone agree? I've cast a reopen vote.

Comment: Seems on-topic to me. I voted to reopen. Need a few more...

Comment: I agree with your interpretation. Casted the 3rd vote

Comment: Looks like it either failed to reopen,  or was closed again. I changed the question title to make it not appear to be a "choice" question.

Comment: @HorusKol it was closed again...